# VBA in Excel 2013 - Launching batch file

Tags: excel, vba

Early Note : I do not code in VBA and i understand this based on programming logic.

I have received a document from one of our department where the macro basically does 3 things.

1) create xml file in temp folder

2) create batch file in document folder

3) run batch file in document folder

Upon further check on how to code on VBA and understanding the logic , i found the line where it calls for the Batch File.

Below is the code :

```
Sub Process_TRD()

    Dim r As Integer

    Dim TRDcommand As String
    Dim myFileName As String
    Dim file2Write As Integer




    TransferDeskPath = RegKeyRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Redacted\Install\MainDir") & "SSC\bin\"
    TransferDeskDrive = Left(RegKeyRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Redacted\Install\MainDir"), 2)

            If SunUser = "" Or SunPass = "" Then
                Load frmPwd
                frmPwd.Show
'            Else
'                SunUser = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PWD").Cells(1, 1)
'                SunPass = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PWD").Cells(1, 2)
            End If

            If SunPass <> "" And SunUser <> "" Then

                myFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & Application.PathSeparator & "Documents" & "\TRD.BAT"
                file2Write = FreeFile()
                If Len(Dir$(myFileName)) > 0 Then
                    Close #file2Write
                    Kill myFileName
                End If

                Open myFileName For Output As file2Write
                Print #file2Write, "C:"
                Print #file2Write, "CD\"
                Print #file2Write, "CD """ & TransferDeskPath & """ "


                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZAS" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZAS"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZDR" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZDR"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZSH" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZSH"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZYH" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZYH"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ASB" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ASB"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "DRB" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_DRB"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "SHK" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_SHK"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "YHM" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_YHM"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "JWM" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_JWM"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZJW" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZJW"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "MKL" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_MKL"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZMK" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZMK"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "RKL" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_RKL"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZRK" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZRK"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If


                 If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "YHP" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_YHP"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZYP" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZYP"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "PLR" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_PLR"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZPL" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZPL"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "CHR" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_CHR"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZCH" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZCH"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "VKL" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_VKL"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZKL" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZKL"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "VPG" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_VPG"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZVP" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZVP"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If
                 If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "H25" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_H25"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "TJR" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_TJR"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                 If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZTJ" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZTJ"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "VKN" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_VKN"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                 If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZVK" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZVK"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "RES" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_RES"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                 If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZRE" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZRE"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "TMM" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_TMM"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                 If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZTM" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZTM"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "GIR" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_GIR"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                 If Sheets("SOE_Import").Cells(2, 3) = "ZGI" Then
                    TRDcommand = "@AutomationDesk.exe -p ""SOE_Import_ZGI"" -u " & SunUser & " -x " & SunPass
                    Print #file2Write, TRDcommand
                End If

                Print #file2Write, "@echo . "
                Print #file2Write, "@echo .   "
                Print #file2Write, "@echo .   "
                Print #file2Write, "@echo .   "

                Print #file2Write, "@echo Please run Sale_Order_Listing Q&A file to check data"
                Print #file2Write, "Pause"
                Close #file2Write
                'Call Shell(myFileName, vbMinimizedNoFocus)
                 Shell (myFileName)

                'MsgBox "Delete and Re-process TRD are done!!!" & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & "   Please run item #5 (Check whether already import any local BUs data !!!"

            Else
                MsgBox "   There is no Sun user name with password has been entered!!!"

            End If

End Sub
```

Question is : why doesnt the macro launch the batchfile even though execCmd is already there?

Regards,
Nasrul

Comment: What is `UserDocumentFolder`? A global Var? Is it filled at all? Does it contains any space characters?

Comment: As @FunThomas mentioned that is a question. If you do not know what is this - try replacing it with `Environ("USERPROFILE")  & application.PathSeparator & "Documnets"`

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak , Environ or Enviroment ?

Comment: @FunThomas - UserDocumentFolder points back to "MyDocument" or "Document" root folder for the user. Example C:\Users\Nasrul\Documents

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin it is Environ, just copy that part

Comment: ```myFileName = Environ("USERPROFILE") & application.PathSeparator & "Documents" & "\TRD.BAT" ```

Comment: As such? @VitaliyPrushak

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin Yes, and the file "TRD.BAT" should be placed to that folder

Comment: Hi @VitaliyPrushak , it does the same as the original code. TRD.Bat does exist by the way. Its just not launching.

Comment: @Andreas in answer posted same as I was going to post

Answer (score 1):

I always use Shell function to run cmd files.
I have never heard of ExecCmd.

```
 shell(myFileName)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function

If you need the VBA code to wait for cmd to finnish, then you can use Wscript.Shell:

```
Dim wsh As Object
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

wsh.Run myFileName, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
```

Edit:

```
Print #file2Write, "@echo Please run Sale_Order_Listing Q&A file to check data"
Print #file2Write, "Pause"
Close #file2Write
DoEvents ' this line
'Call Shell(myFileName, vbMinimizedNoFocus)
Shell (myFileName)
```

Comment: Hi , the created batch file still doesnt launch.

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin Are you sure? Add a `pause` at the end of the bat-file, that will halt the run and not auto close.

Comment: Yes very sure, the batch file didnt even open. Pause added to the script. Old TRD.BAT is renamed to TRD1 so that new Batch File can be generated with Pause. Yes sir very sure the batch file didnt even launch.

Comment: In that case we need the full code of `SomeProcessName`

Comment: SUre , will add this into the post, give me 1minute

Comment: @Andreas Or, at the very least, a Breakpoint adding to the `Shell` command, so that we can confirm that it is being reached and executed...

Comment: Thanks! The only thing I could think of is to add a DoEvents between closing myfile and shell-ing it. DoEvents makes sure windows get the time it needs to finnish what it does (such as writing the file and closing it) before VBA continue.

Comment: Im sorry my friends, but i lost you guys there. VBA isnt my language as i do in C#. This is literally my first day touching VBA.

Comment: Does it help if i mention that this same code works on another PC? Only this remote desktop server it does not work.

Comment: Added DoEvents - no error prompts and batch file still doesnt run.

Comment: Yes. That is a very vital part you left out.

Comment: What does `msgbox dir(myfilename)`return? This shows 0 if the file does not exist, or the filename if it does exist.

Comment: it returns the filename

Comment: In that case It's probably because of the remote thing. The file exists but does not run.